# Nhibernate parent child relationship where child does not reference the parent

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, domain-driven-design, parent-child, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a domain where the children don't reference the parents. I am using nh 3+ and fluent nh with automapping. An example would be like this.

```
public class Parent
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Child> Children {get;set;}
}

public class Child
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public Guid ParentId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string SomethingElse {get;set;}
}
```

When I add a child to my parent collection and save I get an error (sql) saying can't insert the value null into `ParentId`. Column doesn't allow nulls

the `HasMany` mapping would be like this

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.Children).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

There must be someway to do this. I know about inverse but you would put inverse on the reference map of the child to the parent and as my child doesn't have a reference to the parent that wont work.